# Free way to develop Windows CE apps?

Tags: windows, gratis, software-development

I got an ARM-based Windows CE 5 device, and I tried to make apps for it.

But I had to install VS 2005 Professional.

Using VS 2005 Professional and Win CE SDK Standard will offer a full development environment (such as compiler, gui editing, etc.). Nothing else matters, but it's non-free. I want a freeware alternative.

I don't need all of these, but at least, I need:

- C/C++ compiler (or C#, for target)
- Standard library

What alternative can I try?

Comment: Have you tried [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 has a community edition, which is free.

Comment: Will it work with CE 5? I tried installing SDK with VS 2015 Community installed, but it told me some error.(I don't remember them but it was about native and something else.)